# Cron expression to poll file after every 30 mins between 10pm to 1am is not working

Tags: cron, mule

This is my cron expression -

```
0 0,30 22-23,0-1 * * ?
```

I wanted to read a file every 30 minutes from 10pm to 1am everyday. That means it should read a file at 10pm, 10.30pm, 11pm, 11.30pm, 12am, 12.30am, 1am.

But above expression is reading the file at **1.30am** also which I do not want. 
It should exclude 1.30am time.

Am I doing something wrong here? Could anyone suggest me the useful changes or issues in above expression?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The issue with running past the 01 hour limit is due to the job running at :00 and :30. This limitation will require 2 separate cron jobs. One to run at the :00 minute and one to run at :30. This is needed in order to make the 00-01 hour limit prevent the job from running at 1:30AM.

1st job at :00 minute:

```
0 0 22-23,0-1 * * ?
//At second :00, at minute :00, 
//every hour between 22pm and 23pm every hour between 00am and 01am, of every day
```

2nd job at :30 minute with top hour limit set to 00 instead of 01

```
0 30 22-23,0 * * ?
//At second :00, at minute :30, at 00am, 
//and every hour between 22pm and 23pm, of every day
```

Here is an example of runtimes for both jobs:

```
1st job:
Thu Feb 28 22:00:00 UTC 2019
Thu Feb 28 23:00:00 UTC 2019
Fri Mar 01 00:00:00 UTC 2019
Fri Mar 01 01:00:00 UTC 2019

2nd job:
Thu Feb 28 22:30:00 UTC 2019
Thu Feb 28 23:30:00 UTC 2019
Fri Mar 01 00:30:00 UTC 2019
```

A great resource for playing around with Cron statements is the [Cron formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) website, which will let you enter statements, then give you the plain English logic that the statement will follow. It also shows which sections of the statement resolve to minutes, hours, days, ect.. It is really helpful for creating new statements in my opinion.

Comment: I would guess that this won't actually fire at 1am?

Comment: Oh, yes, I did not notice that requirement. You are right. I will update.

Comment: Actually, I see that I missed the midnight and 1am hours as well. Plus this will run at 1:30 as you wanted to avoid. This will require 2 separate cron jobs. I will update.

Comment: Ok, the update should finally take care of all your requirements. With two Cron jobs, you can limit the 30 minute run from running past your 1AM limit.

Comment: Since, I have to use expression in Poll mule component, I can not use two jobs at the same time. But I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could mark as the answer since it is the only way to complete in Cron expressions. Even though it does not work for you in Poll mule component, other users may find the question/answer helpful in later searches.

Answer (score 0):

Your current cron expression should fire @ 1:30am because it includes the hour 1, and the minutes are 0,30.

You could accomplish this with two cron expressions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21274226/10441990

Or you could use an expression filter:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54692465/10441990